# Angular binding checkbox to BehaviorSubject

Tags: angular, rxjs

In Angular how can I bind a checkbox to an rxjs `BehaviorSubject`? I would like changes in the checkbox to trigger the subscription which performs a few operations. Currently I have the following hacked up:

```js
openSessionsOnly$ = new BehaviorSubject(false);
```

and this is in my template:

```html
<input type="checkbox" #openSessionsOnly [checked]="openSessionsOnly$.value" (change)="openSessionsOnly$.next(openSessionsOnly.checked)"/>
```

While it works, I feel like I'm doing something wrong. I tried using `[(ngModel)]`, but it doesn't appear to work with observables. Do I need to use separate property and event bindings like I already have?

Comment: Why do you need to bind `BehaviourSubject` with checkbox? There are events in `input` that you can use to do something when value changes.

Comment: Valid question. I'm used to Knockout.js but maybe even then I was doing something unwise. I'm looking for the cleanest way to recalculate the visible sessions based on the new checkbox value. The answer below is what I was thinking.

Comment: You can use 'change' or 'input' (input events)  to fire some event. You don't need to use `BehaviourSubject`. But if you need, you can use `change` and inside `.next()` some value. No need to add `set` and `get`. It will be cleaner solution.

Comment: How might that be different and cleaner from what I'm already doing? How might the UI be updated from the code in that case?

Comment: Ok, you are right.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is easily accomplished using a TypeScript property:

```js
private openSessionsOnly$ = new BehaviorSubject(false);

get openSessionsOnly(): boolean {
  return this.openSessionsOnly$.value;
}
set openSessionsOnly(v: boolean) {
  this.openSessionsOnly$.next(v);
}
```

In the template now you can bind events or use directly `ngModel`:

```html
<!-- you will need a name if inside a form -->
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="openSessionsOnly" />
```

Please pay attention that you have no guarantee that the next will be called the minimum number of times possible, so you might want to throw a `distinctUntilChanged` in the observable pipe.

Comment: This is the sort of thing I had in mind, but I guess I was hoping it could be done without extra functions and your comment on the execution count is noted. I'm coming from Knockout.js (for better or worse) so I'm just trying to do what I'm used to.

Comment: well, there is not that much code to remove... you have 6 lines for the property definition, which are somewhat verbose, but there is nothing there that can break. ngModel does its thing automagically, and you are free to use observables in the way you prefer.

Comment: This achieves what I was looking for I think, and I learned a bit about typescript. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Did you consider using reactive form controls ? 
No need to reinvent the wheel, angular support this out of the box. 
you can have a reactive form group, which has a reactive form control for your checkbox, and angular will handle value changes observable for you, all you need to do is pipe to the observable reactive forms provide and then use a switch operator based on your need, for example [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) (will cancel previous subscription) in case a new value was emitted or [exhaustMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/exhaustmap) (will prevent new subscription until current one completes)

example

```
<form [formGroup]='formGroup'> 
<input type='checkbox' formControlName='checkboxControlName' value='true' />
</form>  

component
  formGroup = new FormGroup({
    checkboxControlName: new FormControl(false),
  });

ngOnInit(){
//Filter is in case you need to make sure the checkbox is checked. 
this.formGroup.get('checkboxControlName').valueChanges.pipe(
     filter(val) => val === true), 
     switchMap(val => add your new subscription here));
}
```

[Further Read](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

Comment: Another search forced me to learn a bit about reactive forms. From my limited knowledge, I think your answer is good, but the other answer can just be dropped in so I've chosen it.